# R: How do I concatenate decimal number value and string in print statement?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple print statement in R.

```
print("correlation: " + cor(data$Height, data$Weight))
```

But I get an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Of course, printing either the string or the correlation function by themselves work. Is this something that the R programming language can't handle? (ie concatenating two items).

By the way, this doesn't work either.

```
correlation <- cor(data$Height, data$Weight)
print("correlation: " + correlation)
```

I have tried to query Google using a variety of search terms which didn't help and read the help(print) R documentation which confuses me even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `paste0()`

```
paste0("correlation: ", cor(data$Height, data$Weight))
```

You can wrap that in `print()` if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat`

```
cat("correlation: " ,cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl),"\n")
correlation:  -0.852162
```